# Como faço para executar funções quando a janela estiver fora de foco?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Explicando o problema**

Estou trabalhando com sockets, e gostaria de saber como faço para colocar uma notificação apenas quando a tab estiver fora de foco.

Isto é, quando o usuário estiver visualizando a tab, ele não irá receber notificações, mas se ele sair daquela tab, ele receberá novas notificações

O que eu preciso mesmo é de uma função parecido com o `.blur()` do Jquery, mas essa função precisa funcionar como um *listener*, isto é, ela fica lá sempre ativada esperando que algo aconteça. O problema da `.blur()` é que ela é disparada apenas quando a janela perde o foco.

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    console.log("Isto será executado apenas quando eu clicar em outra tab")
}
```

**Resumindo**

Eu preciso de uma função que seja executada em tabs que não estejam em foco do usuário conforme ele vai recebendo novas notificações em tempo real.

Pode ser Javascript ou Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução extremamente simples com jquery. Eu nem acredito que eu não pensei nisso antes.

```
var notification;

$(window).focus(function(){
    notification = false;
});

$(window).blur(function(){
    notification = true;
});
```

Desse jeito quando a janela ganhar foco, ele irá **ATIVAR** as notificações, e quando perder o foco, irá **DESATIVAR** as notificações. Isso sem precisar de muitas linhas de código, ou qualquer tipo de `listening`.

Para receber as notificações, caso a janela esteja fora de foco. Apenas adicionei um `if`.

```
socket.on('newMessage', function(message) {
    if (notification) {
        notifyMe(message.text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione e remova o listener para o evento de acordo com o blur e focus do campo.

```
function removeListener(nome) {
    socket.removeListener(nome);
}

function receberNotificacoes () {
    socket.on('notificacoes', function (dados) { ... });
}

window.addEventListener('focus', receberNotificacoes);
window.addEventListener('blur', removeListener('notificacoes'));
```